# In a random walk simulation, how do I get the mean and standard deviation of how many times the walk returns to the origin?

Tags: python, simulation, random-walk

So I'm simulating a 1-dimensional random walk, with 1000 walks that each take 1000 steps.

How do I calculate the average number of times that a walker returns to the origin and then the standard deviation of the number of times that a walker returns to the origin?

I feel like I'm not understanding the logic of how to manipulate this to get the answers I need, so if anyone could help, that'd be really helpful! The code I have for now is:

```
def StepsFunc() :
    step = np.random.randint( 2 )

    #step is 0 or 1, want -1 or +1
    if step == 0 :
        step = -1
    return step

#defining another function, which will actually take N number of steps
def Move( N ) : 
    x = 0 # starting from origin position
    i = 0 # count
  
    while i <= N-1 :
        step = StepsFunc()
        x += step
        i += 1
    return x

#number of steps
N = 1000

#number of random walks
walks = 1000

StepsList=[]

num=0
for i in range(walks):
    x = Move( N )
    if x == 0:
        num += 1    
    StepsList.append( x )
    

print("The random walk returns to zero {} times".format(num))
print(np.mean(StepsList)) #average of all walks
print(num/walks) #getting the average number of walks that returned to zero?
#plt.hist(StepsList, bins='auto')
```

#####################################################################

UPDATED CODE:

#####################################################################

```
def Move( N ) : 
    x = 0 # starting from origin position
    i = 0 # count
    steps = [] # history of all positions after each step
    for i in range(N) :
        step = StepsFunc()
        x += step
        steps.append(x)
    return steps

N = 1000 
walks = 1000 

StepsList=[] 

for i in range(walks):
    StepsList.append(Move( N ))
    
ZerosList = []
for x in StepsList:
    temp = 0
    for y in x:
        if y == 0:
            temp += 1
    ZerosList.append(temp)
```

I was able to use this to then calculate the mean and standard deviation.

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE PROVIDE US THE CHANGED CODE? THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: @Tsiantakis yeah, sure. I've added it.

Comment: thanks mate nice and clear code.Understandable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, you aren't tracking the number of times a walk reaches zero or even if a walk reaches zero at any point. Your `Move` function returns the last position of the walk, so you are only checking whether the 1000th step is zero. You should change  `Move` to store the count of how many times that walk reaches zero. You can then determine the mean and standard deviation of the number of times a walk returns to zero.

Comment: Ok so I just tried this and you're right, I got the values, thank you!